# How can I override confirm dialog box in Dropzone.js?

Tags: dropzone.js

I am trying to implement dropzone on my project. I have created a custom confirm dialog box and I have used it on every parts of my project. I want to use the same custom confirm dialog box on dropzone as well. How can I do it?

```
const initDropzone = (obj) => {
const newobj = obj;
console.log(newobj);
console.log(newobj.options);
newobj.confirm = function (question, accepted, rejected) {
  console.log('asking question');
  mscConfirm({
    title: 'Management Console',
    subtitle: question,
    dismissOverlay: true,
    onOk() {
      accepted();
    },
  });
};
return newobj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me... I have added this code:

```
$("div#resource_upload_{{ $lecture->id }}").dropzone({ 

    // here go your other dropzone options

    // this option stops the files form auto-uploading
    autoProcessQueue: false,

    // here we add the question
    init: function (){

    // get the dropzone object
    myDropzone = this;

    // overwrite the addedfile function 
    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(event) {

        // this is my confirm function, you can insert your
        var r = confirm("Press a button!");

        if (r == true) {
            txt = "You pressed OK!";
            // this starts the upload proces....
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        } else {
            // ...or not
            txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
        }
    });
});
```

So, autoProcessQueue stops the files from uploading, and then you overwrite the "addedfile" function, and do as you please in it. 
myDropzone.processQueue() continues the file upload.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the default confirm.

```
Dropzone.confirm = function(question, accepted, rejected) {

    showConfirm(question);


    $(document).on('click', '#accept-confirm', function() {
        hideConfirm();
        accepted();
    });

}
```

I'm jus trying to figure out how to handle accepted & rejected myself though because my way only allows me to remove one uploaded file. After the first one I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

It is in the docs under http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods but there's not much info about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the removedFile function, you can add customised script to confirm deletion as the file preview won't be automatically removed.

For example:

```
new Dropzone("#dropzone_container", {
        autoDiscover: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        maxFiles: 10,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        //This will override the removedfile event 
        removedfile: function (file) {

               //This is where you can add custom script to confirm deletion; 
               //You could use Sweetalert 2 or whatever you prefer than the ugly JS ugly alert box

               //This will manually removed the file
               file.previewElement.remove();
        }
);
```

Comment: This event appears to fire after the fact. I call it and the confirm still appears. Looking at the source, removedFile is called once user has Okayed `confirm`